# What is the command to minimize the gnome terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

How can I minimize the Terminal window using a command? For example: I use the `clear` command to clear the terminal output, which command can I have to use to minimize the terminal window?

Comment: http://ss64.com/bash/ is a good bash reference, but it does not mention window placement or display.

Comment: Atually `bg %0` where 0 is the pid of the Terminal Window would send it to the background, not quite the same, but similar :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use this command:

```
xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool getactivewindow)
```

You can change `xdotool getactivewindow` with a specific window that you would like to minimize.

`xdotool` wouldn't be installed on Ubuntu by default.So run the below command to install `xdotool` package.

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Comment: same command Will not work in Raspberry pi..????

Comment: @sunil Do you have xdotool installed on the raspberry pi?

Comment: You can actually chain the 2 xdotool commands in one (instead of running xdotool twice). Ref: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214221 (tried on Ubuntu 16.04)
Command: xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the byobu terminal, you can press F6 to detach from the current session.  This will have the effect of closing the window, but continuing to run byobu and all its subprograms in the background.  To reattach to that session, just run byobu again as you normally would.